# Chrome now treating IP address of localhost same as somesite.localhost

Tags: google-chrome, iis, localhost, vagrant, hosts

For a while I have been running two different server environments on my Windows 7 OS. IIS runs on 127.0.0.1 and I have a Vagrant VM that uses 192.168.33.10. My hosts file looks something like:

- vagrantsite1.localhost 192.168.33.10
- vagrantsite2.localhost 192.168.33.10
- iissite1.localhost 127.0.0.1
- iissite2.localhost 127.0.0.1

Up until a week or so back, this setup worked perfectly fine, however something has changed recently with my Chrome browser. Now all of a sudden in Chrome when I access vagrantsite1.localhost it is referencing the IIS 127.0.0.1 IP address instead of 192.168.33.10. I checked this using **chrome://net-internals/#dns** and even cleared the host cache, which did not seem to resolve anything.

After some research I have found if I add **localhost 192.168.33.10** to my hosts file, the vagrant sites work, however now my IIS sites try to access this IP instead of 127.0.0.1. It seems that Chrome does not let me use a different IP for **somesite.localhost** from **localhost** entry. This is not a problem in IE and Firefox, and up until recently it was not a problem in Chrome.

I was wondering if anyone else has this problem or a potential solution (rather than manually setting localhost IP each time I want to switch servers)? I realize I can use a different port number for one of the servers as a solution, however since everything works fine in IE and Firefox, and until recently worked fine in Chrome, I would like to know the cause.

Comment: What IP shows when you ping vagrantsite1.localhost? If it show 127.0.0.1 it might be a mis-configuration

Comment: When I ping vagrantsite1.localhost I get 192.168.33.10. When I look in Chrome at chrome://net-internals/#dns after I clear host cache and visit vagrantsite1.localhost, I see new entry for localhost 127.0.0.1. It's as if Chrome is getting confused thinking that vagrantsite1.localhost = localhost, which is not the case. As mentioned this only happens in Chrome, Firefox and IE appear to be resolving the correct IP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a "feature" that was just added to chrome, all localhost domains will always resolve to loopback.

See the following links for more information:

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=455825
- https://codereview.chromium.org/938093003

One workaround is to change your entries to not end in localhost, something like "vagrantsite1.local 192.168.33.10" instead should work.

Comment: Thank you, this is frustrating when new "features" like this get introduced and end up causing havoc. I prefer to use the .localhost extension but will switch to local for now.

Comment: Just had this exact moment of realisation! Thanks for confirming my suspicions. A dev server called client.localhost had stopped working. Various different errors shown but all because they were being resolved to the dev's own machines (in Chrome).