# Chrome redirects .dev to https

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, ssl, https, laragon

Suddenly Google Chrome redirects my virtual-host domain myapplication.dev to https://myapplication.dev. I already tried to go to

> chrome://net-internals/#hsts

And enter myapplication.dev into the textbox at the very bottom "Delete domain security policies" but this had no effect.

I also tried to delete the browser data.

What I also did is to change the v-host to .app instead of .dev but Chrome still redirected me to https:// ...

It's a Laravel application running on Laragon.
On other PCs in the same network, it works perfectly.

Comment: For mac users using Valet, you can do `valet secure projectname` to begin using secured connections, thus allowing it to work with chrome.

Comment: The problem is explained here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508357/why-laravel-redirects-to-https-even-in-local-environment/49508409#49508409

Comment: This is also a problem with machines called dev, `http://dev/demo`

Answer (score 53):

There is no way to prevent Chrome (>= 63) form using https on `.dev` domain names.
Google now owns the official `.dev` tld and has already stated that they will not remove this functionality.

The recommendation is to use another tld for development purposes, such as `.localhost` or `.test`.

More information about this update can be found in [this article by Mattias Geniar](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/).

Comment: It would be nice if you can provide a link where to dig into it.

Comment: I added a link to an article that I thought gives the best explanation.

Comment: Google own this tld on what's call the internet, now they act like thye have the upperhand on all networks. And messing with ones where the www DNS convention has no legitimacy.

Comment: Hello Firefox, my old friend.

Comment: But! Don't use .localhost if you're using a local server that's not actually on the localhost IP address (e.g. I had a Vagrant machine set up as something.localhost using the hostsupdater plugin) as [Chrome also redirects that to the loopback address regardless of your DNS settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30645489/300836)!

Comment: Firefox does this now too for .dev domains so say goodbye to that old friend I guess :-)

Comment: This is done by both chrome and firefox. That means firefox also owns by Google?

Comment: It is recommended to use HTTPS even for develop environments
https://youtu.be/kBkX30Cj7Bw?t=1835

Answer (score 8):

This problem can't be fixed. Below is the reason:

1. Google owns .dev gTLD
2. Chrome forces HTTP to HTTPS on .dev domain directly within the source code.

From the 2nd link below:

```
...
// eTLDs
// At the moment, this only includes Google-owned gTLDs,
// but other gTLDs and eTLDs are welcome to preload if they are interested.
{ "name": "google", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https", "pins": "google" },
{ "name": "dev", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https" },
{ "name": "foo", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https" },
{ "name": "page", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https" },
{ "name": "app", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https" },
{ "name": "chrome", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https" },
...
```

#### References

- [ICANN Wiki Google](https://icannwiki.org/Google)
- [Chromium Source - transport_security_state_static.json](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/63.0.3239.118/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json#255)

Answer (score 8):

For Firefox:
you can disable the property **network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist** by visiting the address : **about:config** .

For IE it seems to be still working  .

For Chrome, there is no solution, I think it's hardcoded in the source code.

See that article :  [How to prevent Firefox and Chrome from forcing dev and foo domains to use https](https://tutoref.com/how-to-prevent-firefox-and-chrome-from-forcing-dev-and-foo-domains-to-use-https/)

Answer (score 5):

Check that link

https://laravel-news.com/chrome-63-now-forces-dev-domains-https

Based on this article by Danny Wahl he recommends you use one of the following: “.localhost”, “.invalid”, “.test”, or “.example”.

Answer (score 5):

**Chrome 63 forces .dev domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS**
and soon all other browsers will follow.

.dev gTLD has been bought by Google for internal use and can not be used anymore with http, only https is allowed. See this article for further explanations:

https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Answer (score 4):

**MacOS Sierra, Apache**: After Chrome 63 forces .dev top level domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS phpmyadmin on my mac stop works. I read [this](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/) and just edit `/etc/apache2/extra/http-vhosts.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/.../phpMyAdmin-x.y.z"
  ServerName phpmyadmin.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

and restart apache (by `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl stop; sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl start` ) - and now it works on *http://phpmyadmin.localhost* :) . For laravel applications solution is similar.

The nice thing is that using `*.localhost` top level domain when you set up new project you can forget about editing `/etc/hosts`.

How cool is that? :)

> There's also an excellent proposal to [add the .localhost domain as a
> new standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-let-localhost-be-localhost-06), which would be more appropriate here.

### UPDATE 2018

Using `*.localhost` is not good - some applications will not support it like cURL (used by php-guzzle) - more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442382/guzzle-exception-with-localhost-domains). Better is to use `*.local`.

Answer (score 4):

May be worth noticing that there are other TLD that are forced to https: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/63.0.3239.118/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json#262

`google`, `dev`, `foo`, `page`, `app` and `chrome` right now.