# Vagrant Vhost domains (app.dev) You cannot visit right now because the website uses HSTS. on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, vagrant, homestead

Actually Im using Vagrant/homestead that has three projects that each one has it own vhost app1.dev app2.dev app3.dev. Until three days ago everything works perfect but yesterday when tries to run on chrome/safari throw me an error about SSL **You cannot visit right now because the website uses HSTS**.
On safari it is easy to skip this problem but what can I do for chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome redirects .dev to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768289/chrome-redirects-dev-to-https)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your `.dev` domains to `.test` in your `Homestead.yaml` file then run `vagrant destroy && vagrant up`. Then make sure you type into your browser the full url https://app1.dev. Also ensure you update your hosts files with the new TLD.

Comment: This is a temporary fix that includes destroying the machine (with db data etc..) but doesn't fix the issue

Comment: @numediaweb The problem is Chrome no longer recognizes .dev as a local domain since it's now a valid TLD. The only 2 options are 1: Register your `.dev` TLDs or Switch to the designated TLD for local development which include `.test` and `.localhost`. MacOS has issues with `.localhost` which is why Homestead defaults to `.test`

Also: You should never be afraid of destroying a vagrant box. If you "lose" database information then you're not following proper Vagrant conventions that the boxes are disposable and should use the Homestead `dbexport()` alias to dump them before destroying the box.

Comment: Thank you folks for the answers, I laso found this post https://laravel-news.com/chrome-63-now-forces-dev-domains-https . The solution that you suggest works for me :-)

Comment: another good article https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/