# guzzle exception with .localhost domains

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, guzzle, php-curl

On my local machine I have two services (in laravel 5): userBox and mailBox. mailBox use userBox during login using library `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"` and restful API (mailBox send user credential and get info do user exists and have proper access). After [.dev subdomains stopps working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47768289/860099) I decide to use [.localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47874289/860099) subdomain so i have:

```
userbox.localhost
mailbox.localhost
```

I make changes in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` but unfortunatley I get error:

> cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: userbox.localhost (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

So i look on internet and found solution: we just need add new subdomains to `/etc/hosts`. After that old error was solved but new one appears:

> ClientException in RequestException.php line 113: Client error: `GET
>   http://userbox.localhost/api/v1/users/auth?username=test_manager%40example.com&password=xxxxxxx&MAILBOX_TOKEN=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy`
>   resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:   404 Not Found
>    Not Found (truncated...)

And I don't know how to solve it (link GET http://userbox... from aboce exception works in browser) - **hovewer when I change `userbox.localhost` to `userbox.ddd` then everything works fine.**

**Question:** Do you have any idea how why `.localhost` subdomains not work with `guzzle-curl` and what to do to make it works?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution/workaround for this?

Comment: @DazBaldwin - I write answer however Im not satisfy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I found only one "trivial" (workaround) solution to solve this problem - change userbox domain from `userbox.localhost` to `userbox.local`. However still I don't know why guzzle not support .localhost address.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, It's not really possible with the dev setup for this project. It is a strange quirk!