# Why laravel redirects to https even in local environment?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on Laravel version 5.5. I have one application that needs domain to execute. That's why, I added following entries in my `/etc/hosts` file so that I can open my application using domains like **dashboard.application.dev** or **api.application.dev**. Here is how my `/etc/hosts` file looks like.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   p01ymath
127.0.0.1   dashboard.application.dev
127.0.0.1   api.application.dev
```

I am serving my application using `php artisan serve --port=80` so that I can execute my application using plain development domain names. Yes,  have turned off apache,nginx or any other server that runs on the port **80**.

The issue is, when I try to open **dashboard.application.dev** or **api.application.dev**, It is getting redirected to `https` version of the application. I have cleared cache using `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan optimize` but nothing works.

Here is how my **AppServiceProvider** looks like. It says that if the application is not on the *local* environment, redirect to https version.

```
public function boot()
{
    if (!App::environment('local')) {
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```

But my application is in *local* environment. My `APP_ENV` directive in `.env` file is set to `local` which means the application must not redirect me to https version. I even tried to clean cache on my browser and tried to open the application in another browser that I never use. Still, the issue remains unsolved.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there anything in the .htaccess that could induce that behaviour? if on that boot function, you do `dd(App::environment('local'))` what does it output?

Comment: What browser? I've read Chrome is going to do that automatically for all `.dev` domains.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome 63 (out since December 2017), will force all domains ending on .dev (and .foo) to be redirected to HTTPS via a preloaded HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) header. [You can find more information about this here.](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/)

Change domain to .local or .test

Comment: yes. I changed my domains to `.test` and they are working perfectly!