# Laravel, Apache

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I created a virtual host on apache localhost, when I try to access it on the browser it's saying "Your connection is not pricate".
Here's the virtual host from  httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/newkolabo/public"
    ServerName kolabo.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to connect to it via https instead of http.

Comment: Ok even if i use http it's refusing

Comment: What happens if you try to connect via http? Is there any information in the apache error logs?

Comment: it's saying your connection is not private as well.

Comment: Hah, I forgot about this one. Chrome forces dev and app to https. Try using `.local` or `.test` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768289/chrome-redirects-dev-to-https

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome redirects .dev to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768289/chrome-redirects-dev-to-https)

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to edit your hosts file. Also there are some problems with your virtual config file.

Try this.

In your hosts file

```
127.0.0.1  localhost kolabo.dev
::1        localhost kolabo.dev
```

In virtual config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/public"
ServerAdmin admin@localhost
ServerName kolabo.dev
ServerAlias kolabo.dev

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/public">
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Same problem , it's going to https on it's own and give me the private connection error

Answer (score 0):

#### #1 Wrong Date & Time

Your computer or device's date & time have changed to be an incorrect value. It could be sooner or later but will make your browser can't verify the SSL certificate. That said, your browser will display this error to notify you. To resolve, you need to check your date & time again and make sure they are correct.

#### #2 Antivirus Blocked SSL Connection

Besides the wrong date & time configuration, your antivirus software can block all SSL connections as well, especially if it has the SSL scanning feature, as seen on here. In this case, you can turn off your antivirus software temporarily to verify it's the cause or not. Also, you can locate the SSL scanning feature and turn it off.

#### #3 Invalid Google Chrome's Cookies & Cached Files

According to reports from users, many of them have cleared all cookies, and cached files in Google Chrome and this irritating error was gone. So, it could be caused by invalid cookies or cached files. To fix it, simply clean up all those details. Besides, resetting your Google Chrome would be helpful, but make sure you have backed up bookmarks and saved passwords. Otherwise, all those details will be deleted. You can also use Google Sync to back up those critical details.

#### #4 Expired SSL Certificates

Turning a website into HTTPS is to make it more secure and protect users' information. Benefits of HTTPS are real, but you also need to purchase SSL certificate to make your website work in the HTTPS version. In some cases, if the owner of the website forgot to renew the SSL certificate, you will get this error when visiting it. In this case, there is nothing you can do to get rid of it, except notify to website owner, as well as bypass it by clicking on the "Proceed" link.

#### #5 Invalid SSL Certificate Setup

If the website owner set up SSL certificate in wrong way, there is no way to access the HTTPS version correctly. Subsequently, you always get this error every time you access that website.

---

Alongside those solutions above, you can also turn off your firewall to get rid of this error (if it was caused this error). Just need to turn it off temporarily to test and then turn it on.

To turn this error message off in Google Chrome for temporary, you can [add the --ignore-certificate-errors tag in the shortcut](http://www.fixotip.com/fix-your-connection-is-not-private-google-chrome/). [Source](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-fix-Your-connections-isn%E2%80%99t-private-problem-when-opening-with-the-Google-Chrome-browser)

Comment: Discovered that it's working in microsoft edge , thank you.