# How to create virtual hosts on xampp while using laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, virtualhost

I have created virtual hosts by going to **C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**
then i wrote this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName   localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/basicwebsite/public"
ServerName   basicwebsite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

and then i went to hosts file in **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc** and wrote this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   basicwebsite.dev
```

then I stopped the apache server and again start it, normally it should have open the laravel application that we are making but when i open browser and typed **basicwebsite.dev** it showed an error in my browser it shows this
[Screenshot of my page when i type the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umiqc.png)

it says **this site cant provide secure connection**.
but it shouldn't have shown this , it should have shown the page.
What to do here?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768289/chrome-redirects-dev-to-https/47768411

Comment: Don't use the `dev` domain in Chrome, use `test` or `local` instead.

Comment: thanks got it correct. appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Laragon provides this feature very well. It is easy to setup virtual host with it beacuse it provides Pretty URLs using

> Auto Virutal Hosts
>   Learn more about laragon [here](https://laragon.org/docs/pretty-urls.html)

Answer (score 0):

`.dev` is blocking by browser. Instead of that use `.loc` or something else